# Is it possible to use ng-repeat in a complex json format?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the json format:

```
{"data": {
    "asd": {
        "index": "2",
        "x": "dsds",
        "y": "dsadsa"
    },
    "sfs": {
        "index": "1",
        "x": "dsds",
        "y": "dsds"
    }
}}
```

I want to display these data index, x and y values using ng-repeat of angularjs. But I couldn't think of what the format will be like inside {{   }}  .

I've already done some research, but most of the people recommend on changing the format. What if changing the format isn't an option? Can I still display it using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataContainer.data">
    <td>{{ value.index }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.x }}</td>
    <td>{{ value.y }}</td>
</tr>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pk7a44f7/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can basically display anything in `ng-repeat` if you are using the correct syntax and accessing the right values.

I've created a demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en3k35z5/1/) that displays all the items in your object.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="APP" ng-controller="TST">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in test_obj.data">
        <p>{{key}}</p>
        <p ng-repeat="(k,v) in val">{{k}} - {{v}}</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var APP = angular.module('APP', []);

APP.controller('TST', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test_obj = {
        "data": {
            "asd": {
                "index": "2",
                "x": "dsds",
                "y": "dsadsa"
            },
            "sfs": {
                "index": "1",
                "x": "dsds",
                "y": "dsds"
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```